# Multiple Boxplots in one HighCharts chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, boxplot

I am trying to show two different boxplots in one chart. This should be possible as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/maw3rd18/3/

In my actual code I have the exact same code as in the fiddle, however it does not work. The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Azr.png). Totally not like a boxplot.

To be precise, in my actual code I use angular-js. I tend to think my issue has something to do with angular.js. I use the `highcharts-ng` module. The boxplots need an additional javascript library from highcharts called `highcharts-more`. Maybe `highcharts-ng` (angular.js module) is not compatible with `highcharts-more` (js library)? I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Check source code then ;) Anyway, for me it looks like `chart.type` doesn't work properly. Try to set that option for each of the series: `series: [{ name: "...", type: "boxplot", data: [...] }]`.

Comment: answer now added. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30914813/973158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, problem was related to declaring the chart-type as a boxplot.

in native highcharts it's done like this (as can be seen in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maw3rd18/3/)):

```
chart: {
    type: 'boxplot'
},
```

However, when using angularjs `highcharts-ng` module, we need to use the following code:

```
options: {
    chart: {type: 'boxplot'}
},
```

That's it.